# Installing Information Server Windows XP

Tags: ibm-information-server

I experienced the following error after installing Information Server Console 8.1 on my windows xp sp2 workstation when I try to log on Information Server Console:

> `"Internal Error: - Failed to load the Java Virtual Machine. The most common cause of this error is a failure of Java virtual machine to allocate enough memory" Check the memory settings in ......\proxy xml.`

I attached `proxy.xml` for your documentation. Besides my workstation has 4 Gb RAM and Sun Java Runtime Environment v `6.0_11`.

> `"Other possible reasons for this failure are that one or more JARS are not present or some other configuration problem exists." Not very disclosing I suppose ...`

I set the environment variables : `XMOG_TRACE_LEVEL= Verbose` and `XMOG_TRACE_FILE=c:\xmogtrace.txt`, tried to log on again, but no file or information is generated on `c:\xmogtrace.txt` and the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following technote in ibm.com which discusses solution for this issue:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=14&uid=swg21370513